# Converting ReactTabulator component to Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, tabulator

I was using [react-tabulator](https://github.com/ngduc/react-tabulator) in JS. Now I'm converting it into TS.

I have three problems:

1. Not sure what's the type argument of `useRef` for `ReactTabulator`

```
import * from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { ReactTabulator } from 'react-tabulator';
import 'react-tabulator/css/bootstrap/tabulator_bootstrap4.min.css';
import { CommonProps } from '../types/properties';

const Workloads = (props: CommonProps) => { 
    // Tabulator reference
    const workloadsTableRef = useRef<???>(null);

    const downloadAsJSON = () => {
        workloadsTableRef.current?.download('json', 'RTP_Workloads.json');
    };

    // Workload Table Column Setup
    const workloadsTableCoumns = [
        // Column Setup
    ];

    // Workload Table Options Setup
    const workloadsTableOptions = {
        // Setup Table Options
    };

    return (
        <>
            <h4 className="text-center">Workloads </h4>
            <div>
                <Button variant="dark" onClick={() => downloadAsJSON()}>
                    Download JSON
                </Button>{' '}
            </div>
            <ReactTabulator
                onRef={(r) => (workloadsTableRef.current = r.current)}
                columns={workloadsTableCoumns}
                options={workloadsTableOptions}
            />
        </>
    );
};

FetchWorkloads.propTypes = {
    api: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default FetchWorkloads;
```

2. I would like to extend a tabulator module of `tabulator-tables` for a custom patch code.

In JS, I would do like this:

```
import { TabulatorFull as Tabulator } from "tabulator-tables";
import SelectEditor from "tabulator-tables/src/js/modules/Edit/defaults/editors/select";

/**
 * Bug Fix - Tablulator headerFilter `select`
 * Issue: when 'X' is clicked to remove filters it clears the filter as expected but the filter list doesn't load unless focussed out.
 */
Tabulator.extendModule("edit", "editors", {
    select: function (cell, onRendered, success, cancel, options) {
        let inputElement = SelectEditor.call(
            this,
            cell,
            onRendered,
            success,
            cancel,
            options
        );

        let listener = function (event) {
            inputElement.blur();
        };

        inputElement.addEventListener("search", listener);
        return inputElement;
    }
});
```

But in TS, I'm unsure on how to import `import SelectEditor`. I have already added `@types/tabulator-tables`.

3. Error : `Types of property 'headerFilter' are incompatible. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Editor | undefined'` for columns setup

```
const workloadsTableCoumns = [
        { title: 'ID', field: 'pID', headerFilter: 'input' },
        {
            title: 'Name',
            field: 'pName',
            download: false,
            headerMenu: headerMenu,
            headerSort: false,
            headerFilter: 'input',
        },
        
        {
            title: 'Task',
            field: 'task_progression.task_name',
            headerMenu: headerMenu,
            headerSort: false,
            mutator: commonMutatorFn,
            headerFilter: 'select',
            headerFilterParams: {
                values: true,
                sortValuesList: 'asc',
            },
        }
]
```

I also checked the respective `.d.ts` files,`TabulatorTypes.d.ts` has the proper types.

```
type Editor = true | 'input' | 'textarea' | 'number' | 'range' | 'tickCross' | 'star' | 'select' | 'autocomplete' | ((cell: CellComponent, onRendered: EmptyCallback, success: ValueBooleanCallback, cancel: ValueVoidCallback, editorParams: {}) => HTMLElement | false);
```

I don't understand why this issue?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!